# Is Logitech MK220 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo compatible with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Is [MK220](http://www.amazon.in/Logitech-MK220-Wireless-Keyboard-Mouse/dp/B008QS7JN4/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1446873922&sr=1-1&keywords=bluetooth%20%20keyboard) compatible with ubuntu 14.04. Am just was searching for a low cost wireless keyboard and mouse for my ubuntu 14.04.

Please comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This upvoted answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/664388) reported that MK220 works on Linux.

> Based on my experience with Logitech Wireless Combo MK220 product, it is running without problems right after plugging into USB on Raspberry Pi [...] running Raspbian Linux.

Like the user who provided the linked answer, I also took the risk to purchase the product even unsupported by the manufacturer. I use **Logitech Wireless keyboard with touchpad K400** that has been working well since 2012. Works well in Xubuntu 14.04.

In short, a product *without* custom features tend to work out-of-box on Linux and so do Ubuntu and the official flavours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, however it is not quite plug and play.

You have to essentially reboot the devices, the easiest way being to cut the power by removing a battery and replacing it. Doing this on both the keyboard and mouse in the K220 gets it working for me everytime.

Answer (score 0):

According to Logitech, it's not. However, keyboards and mice often work just fine in every OS, unless you need support for keybinds or such things.

Having said that, I found this via a search:

http://onubuntu.blogspot.com/2014/08/logitech-mk220-impressions.html

Comment: Thanks... Still I was wandering if I bye this .. Will not I end up with a deadlock of being incompatible with my ubuntu 14.04. Just searching still...

Comment: I find this [Compatible](http://mikebeach.org/2010/06/27/logitech-devices-on-ubuntu-linux-and-others/) also, and it does not have the mk220 design.

Comment: MK220 combo got delivered just now and with ease things works loud and clear in my both ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 boxes without doing anything.....And is a very nice compact product...